# Refreshing a tabbar in iOS app

Tags: ios, tabbar, viewwillappear

In my app I have a tab bar. When I move from one tab to the other the delegate method is not been called.

I am just switching from one tab to the other by a button at that time the ViewWillAppear is not calling. Because of this in the next tab when I hit a button, it is hitting an API and the returned value is not shown to me in my screen. How to overcome this problem?

Following is the line which I have given when a tab button is clicked.

```
**iphoneDelegate.tabbarcontrolObject setSelectedIndex:1**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added this line and got my solution

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the delegate to yourself in the controller where you implement the delegates?

```
[iphoneDelegate.tabbarcontrolObject setDelegate:self] ?
```

Comment: yes i have this as below....[iphoneDelegate.tabbarcontrolObject setDelegate:self]
   [iphoneDelegate.tabbarcontrolObject setSelectedIndex:1]

Comment: And of course you also have set the protocol <UITabBarDelegate> for your controller?

Comment: now i include this in my header file nut still i have the same problem